# Transformer pipeline with 'accelerate' not using gpu?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, accelerate

My transformers pipeline does not use cuda.

code:

```
 from transformers import pipeline, Conversation

# load_in_8bit: lower precision but saves a lot of GPU memory
# device_map=auto: loads the model across multiple GPUs
chatbot = pipeline("conversational", model="BramVanroy/GEITje-7B-ultra", model_kwargs={"load_in_8bit": True}, device_map="auto")
```

Testing for cuda works just fine:

```
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Which prints `True`

I have a project with these libs:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
transformers = "^4.37.2"
torch = {version = "^2.2.0+cu121", source = "pytorch"}
torchvision = {version = "^0.17.0+cu121", source = "pytorch"}
accelerate = "^0.26.1"
bitsandbytes = "^0.42.0"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121"
priority = "supplemental"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

All opensource models are loaded into cpu memory by default. You need to manually call `pipe = pipe.to("cuda:0)` or `pipe = pipe.cuda()` to run it on your GPU. You also need to transfer all your other tensors which take part in the calculation to the same GPU device if you want to finetune a model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll just post more info here, in case anyone else ends up here:

- The model needs loading form disk to GPU. This takes CPU and time
- You need enough GPU VRAM.
- On a bigger GPU take away the `load_in_8bit` so you can use all the memory and compute.